# DSP Library IIR and FIR filters

Tags: audio, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response

Me and a coworker are currently in the process of making an audio dsp library. We are wondering what some good FIR and IIR filters to use were. I know ALOT of them but what do you guys think in best/necessary for audio? Also if you have any other ideas not related to FIR and IIR filters please give your input.

Comment: do you mean code for different FIR and IIR structures?  or do you mean specific FIR and IIR filters, complete with defined coefficients?

Comment: Just to make the structures. I have a general filter function already.

Comment: probably for simple real-time filter effects, you want to cascade 2nd-order sections.  if the filters get modulated a lot, you probably want each 2nd-order section to be a lattice or normalized ladder, but direct-form biquads might work fine.